# Subtrair em angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Estou com uma duvida em AngularJS. Para somar os valores em memória esta tudo ok, mas estou com dificuldade em subtrair um ou mais valores que estão em memória.

```
            $scope.adicionaratividade = function (atividade) {
                $scope.atividades.push(angular.copy(atividade));
                $scope.total += parseFloat($scope.atividade.tempo);
                delete $scope.atividade;
                $scope.atividadeForm.$setPristine();
            };
            $scope.apagaratividades = function (atividades) {
                $scope.total -= parseFloat(atividades.tempo);
                $scope.atividades = atividades.filter(function (atividade) {
                    if (!atividade.selecionado) return atividade;
                });
            };
```

Comment: `atividades` é um objeto ou uma array? O que dá `console.log(typeof atividades, atividades);`?

Comment: Sergio é um array

Comment: Ok, então usar `$scope.total -= parseFloat(atividades.tempo);` não vai dar. O que queres fazer nessa conta?

Comment: Quero pegar o valor total existente em memória e subtrair do mesmo o valor do item excluído.

Comment: Ok, e essa função `function (atividades)` dá-te uma array certo? Então e como sabes o ID do elemento que vai ser apagado? é via `.selecionado`? (ie todos os elementos dessa array com `.selecionado` devem ser tomados em conta)

Comment: Sergio coloquei todo o código da pagina para você ver, assim acredito que será mais fácil você entender como montei a logica.

Comment: Ok, então volto à pergunta inicial aqui nos comentários. O que dá `console.log(typeof atividades, atividades);` com o código que tens na pergunta?

Comment: Eu executei ele no Console do Chrome e deu a seguinte mensagem: 

VM3550:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: atividades is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:32

Comment: Ok, e se usares somente `ng-click="apagaratividades"` O que aparece na consola?

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo erro. Este é o objetivo final que quero ter com estes códigos. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s6/sh/6db363ef-f8c1-4d8f-b619-b87889953cdc/ea1c6f7ebbc930e95f8012687fea9be6

Comment: Como assim aparece o mesmo erro? eu tirei `atividades` do `ng-click`. Podes colocar o erro aqui?